# Opening a bank account in UK as a foreigner

Tags: investing, united-kingdom, banking, bank-account, egypt

I am an Egyptian student planning to complete my post-graduation medical training in the UK.  I was wondering if I could open a bank account to start saving some money that I could use when (or if) I was able to get my medical training there?

Is it possible?

What can I do? How much do I need to invest or to open an account?

Are there any other investment methods as a foreigner?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. My assumption is you are/will be in UK.

> **I am a student from outside the UK and I am about to start studying at a
>   UK university/college/school. How do I choose which bank is best for me?**
>
> You should be able to open a ‘basic bank account’ with a number of different banks. A ‘basic bank account’ provides easy access to banking facilities for adults in the UK. Additionally, some banks offer a bank account tailored specifically for your needs as an international student. There is a table on pages 6 & 7 of this leaflet that has a list of basic accounts and other accounts that may be suitable along with brief descriptions of some of their features.
>   Most banks don’t ask you to pay in any money to open a basic account. You should look around to see which bank and account suit you best and then visit the local branch of the bank you have chosen. You may also be able to get other types of account, as detailed in the next section. Please speak to a bank

Go through the source I have linked. It is a bit old, but has relevant information for you.

[SOURCE](https://www.bba.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/AE249_BBA_International_Students_Oct12.pdf)